# SDL issues (c++)

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm new to C++ and i have been following a tutorial on how to make pong using C++ and SDL. I've been following the tutorial word by word but now I've hit a road block. When i try to run i get an error saying that my SDL functions are not being recognized.

The error i get is: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDLmain': No such file or directory

Here is my code:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include"SDL_ttf.h"

SDL_Surface screen;
SDL_Event occur;

void loadGame()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    TTF_Init();

    SDL_Surface* hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );
}

int main (int argc, char* args[])
{
    loadGame();

    bool running = true;

    while(running == true) 
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not the file that is triggering the error.

Comment: `SDLmain` is probably included by `SDL.h`. Would be good to see how you're calling the compiler, I remember at one point the order of arguments to it mattered.

Comment: This is not related to your problem but you have a global named "screen" and a local variable to loadGame() named "screen". The local variable has priority and your screen will thus never be set properly.

Comment: what does `locate SDL.h` command give? usually it is at `SDL/SDL.h`

Comment: What is your environment (Windows, Linux, ...) ? How are you compiling it?

Comment: windows, using visual c++

Answer (score 0):

You should check your SDL lib and include paths. Make sure you've set the correct directories for your IDE to find the sdlmain files it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Under VC++ Directories, Include directories, you should have C:\sdl2.0\include (or wherever you put SDL and its include subfolder), along with whatever else your projects need.

If this is already set... which version of SDL are you using (1.x or 2.x)?  Is your version of SDL_TTF, and any other SDL add-ons, the same version?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "SDL_main.h" is in the same folder as "SDL.h".

From "SDL.h":

```
//[...]
/**
*  \file SDL.h
*
*  Main include header for the SDL library
*/


#ifndef _SDL_H
#define _SDL_H

#include "SDL_main.h"
#include "SDL_stdinc.h"
#include "SDL_assert.h"
//[...]
```